# Kohana : 'HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: The requested URL addon/about was not found on this server.'

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, kohana

My primary website use Kohana framework. And I want create any directory (addon) with CI framework. I have success access the root of addon directory with addition .htaccess rule in Kohana/primary domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

RewriteRule ^(index\.php|sitemap\.xml|addon) - [PT,L]

RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L,QSA]
```

I success when type site.com/addon.

I have 3 url again in my addon site such us site.com/addon/about, site.com/addon/link, site.com/addon/contact. When I edit again the .htaccess in primary domain to access the another links of my directory, but its failed.

```
RewriteRule ^(addon|addon/about|addon/link|addon/contact) - [PT,L]
```

When I type in URL site.com/addon/about

I got

```
HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: The requested URL addon/about was not found on this server.

SYSPATH/classes/kohana/request/client/internal.php [ 87 ]
```

How to access full or all of my directory file (addon) links without get any trouble ? Because I also check my admin on addon/admin also crash, all function in framework CI will crashed. Solving this is appreciate.

.htaccess CI:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to not rewrite if you are looking to use the addon directory. Something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#forbidden for these folders
RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system) - [F,L]
#do not rewrite requests to addon or test directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/test|/addon)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ can be helpful with `.htaccess` issues.

Comment: but still can not access test.com/addon/about. can help?

Comment: I check and result `No input file specified.` I'm very confused in this case. PLease help